# whatsapp/chat-api v3.2.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system

Tags: php

I am installing guzzle on my laravel application. But before, guzzle requires whatsapp/chat-api. When i install whatsapp/chat-api  by `composer require whatsapp/chat-api`, it throws the error

> > whatsapp/chat-api v3.2.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

However, i have `extension=mcrypt.so` in my php.ini for my php. My PHP version is **7.2.1**

Why am i still getting the error above even after including  `extension=mcrypt.so` in my php.ini ?

Comment: mcrypt was removed in PHP 7.0 as it has been abandoned for years and is no longer considered fit for purpose.  Any software that relies on it must also be considered unfit for purpose until the dependencies on mcrypt are patched out in favour of more modern encryption libraries.

Comment: Is the extionsion **installed** on your system? Check by running `php -i | grep mcrypt`. If the output is empty, it is not.

Comment: @GordonM, meaning Guzzle can't work on PHP 7.0 ?

Comment: @TobiasF. i did and its not installed

Comment: Wait, since when does Guzzle require `whatsapp/chat-api`? Thats news to me. You perhaps meant to say: "I tried to install whatsapp/chat-api, which requires guzzle, which in turn requires ext-mcrypt".

Comment: I couldn't find any references to mcrypt in the current version of guzzle.  If guzzle ever depended on mcrypt in the past then it doesn't now.

Comment: It seems the whatsapp/chat-api depends on `mcrypt`: https://packagist.org/packages/whatsapp/chat-api

Comment: Yes @TobiasF.  It does. When i install guzzle 6.3, it get the error `Problem 1
    - whatsapp/chat-api v3.2.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt `

Comment: Rephrasing the concerns expressed by other commenters: `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:6.3` triggers the installation of `guzzlehttp/promises`, `ralouphie/getallheaders`, `psr/http-message`, `guzzlehttp/psr7` and `guzzlehttp/guzzle` and suggests (but does not install by itself) `psr/log`. The `whatsapp/chat-api` package must come from elsewhere. Are you sure it isn't already inside `composer.json` as direct dependency set by another team member?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, thank you for this.. I had whatsapp/chat-api in my composer.json . I removed it and guzzle is installed now

Answer (score 1):

the WhatsApp API is and of support in 2016  ther is no way you can use this package 
but you can use twillo API to send and receive the message from WhatsApp